# Postgres: Select a timeinterval that spans past midnight

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
 id |    time     
----+-------------
  1 | 21:00:00+01
  2 | 22:00:00+01
  3 | 23:00:00+01
```

Column `id` is of type integer and time is `time with timezone`. I want to select all rows that fall within a specified interval, e.g.,

```
select *
from times
where time >= time '22:30' - interval '60 minutes' and time <= time '22:30' + interval '60 minutes';
```

However, if the intervall extends past midnight, i.e., when I select `23:30` as time argument, then I get an empty result set.

Is there a way to tell postgress to ignore the minutes that span past midnight?

Comment: Curious if you get an answer, I'm currently working with a data store that has a date stamp plus a column that stores time of day in seconds.  Any seconds number higher than 86400 technically spans into the next day.  (used for a company with a service calendar with service that extends past midnight however is considered part of the previous day's service).  Using a  similar model to extract seconds from your date may work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
select *
from times t cross join
     (values ('22:30'::time - interval '60 minutes', '22:30'::time + interval '60 minutes') 
     ) v(fromt, tot)   
where (fromt <= tot and time >= fromt and time <= tot) or
      (fromt > tot and (time >= fromt or time <= tot))
```